# Setting minimum weights for holdings in MATLAB's portfolio optimization tool

Tags: matlab, optimization, finance, portfolio

MATLAB has a portfolio optimization example available [**here**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/portfolio-optimization-examples.html#zmw57dd0e15510). The example shows step-by-step how to construct the efficient frontier for a sample of 30 stocks. My question is in regards to the "Find a Portfolio with a Targeted Return and Targeted Risk" section. Notice that by running

```
aBlotter = dataset({100*awgt(awgt > 0),'Weight'}, 'obsnames', p.AssetList(awgt > 0));

fprintf('Portfolio with %g%% Target Return\n', 100*TargetReturn);
disp(aBlotter);

bBlotter = dataset({100*bwgt(bwgt > 0),'Weight'}, 'obsnames', p.AssetList(bwgt > 0));

fprintf('Portfolio with %g%% Target Risk\n', 100*TargetRisk);
disp(bBlotter);
```

I am able to get weights of the shares that should be held in a portfolio in order to achieve either a target return of 20% or a target risk of 15%.

Is it possible to obtain a portfolio where I can set minimum weights? For example, by running the code above, there are two stocks, INTC and MSFT with weights below 1% in the efficient portfolio. Assume I want only weights above 5%. I modified the above code as follows in order to attempt this:

```
aBlotter = dataset({100*awgt(awgt > 0.05),'Weight'}, 'obsnames', p.AssetList(awgt > 0.05));

fprintf('Portfolio with %g%% Target Return\n', 100*TargetReturn);
disp(aBlotter);

bBlotter = dataset({100*bwgt(bwgt > 0.05),'Weight'}, 'obsnames', p.AssetList(bwgt > 0.05));

fprintf('Portfolio with %g%% Target Risk\n', 100*TargetRisk);
disp(bBlotter);
```

When I run this, MATLAB simply drops the names and weights of the stocks with a weight below 5% in the output, but it doesn't recalculate weightings for the remaining stocks.

I understand that a portfolio with these constraints will not lie exactly on the efficient frontier. For what I'm doing, a portfolio near the efficient frontier is acceptable.

Thank you.

Comment: You need a MIQP (Mixed Integer Quadratic Programming) solver for that. Matlab does not have such a solver in their toolbox. You could model this with an external solver such as Cplex or Gurobi.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Actually, I think Matlab 2016 does have a Mixed INteger Quadratic Programming solver given here : https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/examples/mixed-integer-quadratic-programming-portfolio-optimization.html

Comment: Thank you both. I believe that may be it,  @Abhinav